# select values at specified indices in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I got a list, call in `listIn` with `n` number of elements. I got another list, call it `ind` with `m` elements (`m<n`). `ind` is indices I want to keep in `listIn`, and remove others.

I can do it by running a loop, but I am curious is there is a smart way to do it.

Eg.

```
listIn = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // 11 elements
ind = [4,7,8] // 3 indices

Result = drop all elements excepts ones at 4,7,8.
```

Comment: An example of your code could be very helpful to understand your question

Comment: Im sure you could use LINQ to reduce the number of lines you type, but a loop is probably more readable

Comment: @user574632 Except for very complex operations, a loop is rarely more readable

Comment: @BenAaronson depends what you are used to i think. loop looks cleaner to me.

Comment: just wondering, what is so confusing about the question that i get downvotes .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
listIn = ind.Select(i => listIn[i]).ToList();
```